# how to implement in a threadsafe way once-per-process writes of global shared variables in openmp?

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I want to write a function which

1 is thread-safe, i.e. works correct whether called from inside a openmp parallel region or not,

2 performs a once-per-process (*not*: once-per-thread) write to a global shared variable.

my original thought was to use the `master` or `single` directives, but they fail in nested parallelism. Is there a fail proof solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crude way to do it would be in OpenMP critical region, where you both set an "already set" flag and the shared variable.   As each thread enters the critical region, it tests the already set flag, and

A finer-grained approach would be to use OpenMP locks; you can just have the first thread through set the lock after which other threads can't, and use that as your flag:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void setonce_thread(omp_lock_t *l, int input, int *sharedvar) {
    if (omp_test_lock(l)) {
        printf("Set lock with %d\n", input);
        *sharedvar = input;
    } else {
        printf("Could not set lock with %d\n", input);
    }
}

void setonce_crit(int input, int *setflag, int *sharedvar) {
#pragma omp critical
    {
        if ((*setflag) == 0) {
            (*setflag)++;
            *sharedvar = input;
            printf("Set in crit with %d\n", input);
        } else {
            printf("Could not set in crit with %d\n", input);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    omp_lock_t lck;
    int sharedvar1, sharedvar2;
    int setflag = 0;
    int input = 17;

    omp_set_nested(1);
    omp_set_num_threads(9);
    omp_init_lock(&lck);
#pragma omp parallel shared(lck, sharedvar1, sharedvar2, setflag, input) default(none) num_threads(3)
    {
#pragma omp for
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
#pragma omp parallel shared(lck, sharedvar1, sharedvar2, setflag, input) default(none) 
            {
#pragma omp for
                for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
                    int id=omp_get_thread_num();
                    setonce_thread(&lck, id, &sharedvar1);
                    setonce_crit(id, &setflag, &sharedvar2);
                }
            }
        }
        omp_unset_lock(&lck);
    }
    omp_destroy_lock(&lck);

    printf("Shared Var 1 = %d\n", sharedvar1);
    printf("Shared Var 2 = %d\n", sharedvar2);
    printf("Set Flag     = %d\n", setflag);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the write is only made once per process and not once per thread, then you don't need any synchronization because there's nothing to synchronize it with. Just do the write unprotected.

Comment: I think the OPs question is _how_ to arrange to do it only once per process.